# Dataframe - get most frequent values and their count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

There is a dataframe with a lot of records:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'product'])
```

To get the **most frequent values**:

```
df['product'].value_counts()[10].index.tolist()
```

What I would like to have is also **the count of each value in front of it**.

What is the way to do that?

Comment: How looks expected output? It is DataFrame? list? dict?

Comment: Please post a snippet of data so this is reproducible ([mcve])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `DataFrame` with 2 columns filled by top10 values:

```
 df1 = df['product'].value_counts().iloc[:10].rename_axis('val').reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: what if that column has a list of items?